# What exactly is the qualitative definition of momentum?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, definition

In mostly every book there is the quantitative definition of [momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum), i.e, $p=mv$, what is exactly its qualitative definition?

Comment: What do you want to know?  Obviously momentum is not energy;  equally obviously the fundamental observed laws show momentum conservation in the absence of external forces, in the case of elastic collisions, etc.

Comment: Why should something have both a quantitative and a qualitative definition? I would think that things would have only one or the other, not both.

Comment: @Dale: So physics just reverts to a set of equations without intuitive, qualitative understanding?

Comment: @Not_Einstein I never said that. An intuitive, qualitative understanding is not the same as a definition.

Comment: Well, we can debate the definition of definition. Merriam-Webster includes the following: a statement expressing the essential nature of something.

Answer (score 2):

To quote Merriam-Webster:

*broadly : a property of a moving body that determines the length of time required to bring it to rest when under the action of a constant force.*

So it can be considered as a measure of resistance to a change in motion (Edit: This may be too loose of a statement - see comments below). The larger the momentum, the more time is required for a given force to bring it to rest.

A constant force acting in the opposite direction to the momentum will cause a constant deceleration. The larger the initial v is, the more time it will take to bring the object to rest. Also, the larger m is, then since a = F/m the smaller will be the deceleration produced by the given force.

Comment: if momentum is resistance to change in motion then what is inertia

Comment: Good question. Momentum incorporates inertia - it's the "m" in mv. As mentioned above, for a given m, an object with higher initial velocity requires more time for a force to bring it to rest compared with the same mass moving at a smaller velocity.

Comment: understood. therefore it is momentum which more precisely defines resistance to motion than inertia

Comment: This is an oversimplified definition.  Momentum is the integral of  mass * acceleration  with respect to time, and of course F=ma, so momentum is the integral of force WRT time.